# Is this Wick rotation correct? (self-intersecting closed contour)

Tags: complex-analysis, integration, quantum-field-theory

I wonder if what is [shown in figure 9.1 here is correct](http://www.staff.science.uu.nl/~wit00103/ftip/Ch09.pdf)?

Doesn't the contour self-intersect, i.e. it's not a simple closed curve hence the Residue theorem shouldn't apply to this closed contour, right?

Comment: My answer was topologically incorrect.  As for the contour, I am not sure about the validity, although the guy who wrote the book certainly is.

Comment: The residue theorem holds for any (piecewise) smooth closed curve, even if it is self-intersecting.

Answer (score 2):

If you are referring to the statement

> Since the contour $C$ does not enclose singularities, the integral over $C$ must vanish

this is correct. The contour consists of two simple closed curves, neither of which surrounds any singularities of the function. Therefore, the integral over each part is $0$, hence the total integral is $0$.